# C: modifying const data in an array using pointer

Tags: c, constants, qualifiers

I have an `const` array in global scope like this:

`const long array_test[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`

How do I modify the elements of the above array at runtime using a pointer?

Comment: If you manage to do it, you're invoking undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In no way. You can't modify `const` objects.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't**. The `const` keyword is used to create a **read only variable**. Once initialised, the value of the variable cannot be changed but can be used just like any other variable. That means, a `const` qualified variable must not be assigned to in any way during the run of a program.